# Связь устройства из Device Tree с драйвером

Tags: linux, драйвер, embedded

1) Почитал https://linuxseekernel.blogspot.com/2014/05...-practical.html и, честно говоря, так и не понял какое различие между:

- Platform Driver
- Platform Device

Т.е. это два независимых варианта? Или есть определенные случаи когда стоит что-то конкретное из этого использовать?

2) Есть Device Tree

```
myled: myled@8006a000 {
    Позволяет операционной системе идентифицировать соответствующий драйвер устройства. 
    compatible = "dglnt,myled-1.00.a";
    Адрес и длина области регистров
    reg = <0x8006a000 0x2000>;

    ...
};
```

И кусок кода драйвера.

```
/* Define Driver Name */
#define DRIVER_NAME "myled"

...    ...

/* device match table to match with device node in device tree */
static const struct of_device_id myled_of_match[] = {
   {.compatible = "dglnt,myled-1.00.a"},
   {},
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(of, myled_of_match);

/* platform driver structure for myled driver */
static struct platform_driver myled_driver = {
    .driver = {
         .name = DRIVER_NAME,
         .owner = THIS_MODULE,
         .of_match_table = myled_of_match},
    .probe = myled_probe,
   .remove = myled_remove,
   .shutdown = myled_shutdown
};

/* Register myled platform driver */
module_platform_driver(myled_driver);
```

Если в общих чертах, то благодаря этим ~15 строкам можно связать устройство с драйвером. Но какого-то полного осознания не пришло. **Или забить и считать, что делаем так-то и точка?**

Еще узнал, что, например, PCI и USB самообнаруживаются, но I2C - нет (на самом деле не только шина I2C; там еще масса устройств). Для самообнаруживаюшихся устройств система находит драйвер исходя из 2 номеров производителя. Если устройство не является самообнаруживающимся, то для того, чтобы система поняла, что у нас есть некоторое устройство, необходимо написать в драйвере 15 вышерасполагающихся строчек. 
**Про этот момент тоже хотелось бы услышать мнение специалиста.**

Comment: 1. Вам с точки зрения модели устройств ОС или общего смысла? *Platform driver*, — очевидно, описывает в каком-то виде **драйвер устройства**, тогда как *platform device* — описывает **само устройство**.

Comment: 2. Этими строчками определяется драйвер, который обслуживает совместимые с ним устройства. Всё остальное — внутренности реализации конкретной ОС.

Comment: 3. Всё так, большинство шин не являются автоматически обнаруживаемыми. Поэтому для устройств SPI, I2C, UART и так далее необходимо **где-то** держать эту информацию, как и что подключено (адресуется на шине). Одним из таких способов является описание Device Tree.

Comment: P.S. Ссылка не работает, рекомендуется копировать непонятные моменты сюда, чтобы видно было, что именно вызывает трудности.